# i have a project in IBM Watson studio using jupyter notebook

Tags: python, websphere, ibm-watson

when I try to write my code

```
pip install ibm-cos-sdk
```

I get this error

Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): :1:6: unexpected symbol
1: !pip install

how I can solve it?

Comment: To execute the install in a Jupyter cell, you normally write ```!pip install ibm-cos-sdk```.

Comment: @pinkspikyhairman I tried  ' !pip install ibm-cos-sdk ' and still the same error